# Kerberos - What is an SPN and why is it used

Tags: java, jetty, kerberos, spnego

I am trying to setup SPNEGO in Jetty using these instructions: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Spnego.

What I would like to know is what is the SPN (from googling it looks like some sort of alias) and why is it actually used? (ie what does it add - extra security? if so - why?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPN is the Service Principal Name and is by no means a side characeter in Kerberos. Basically, it is the equivalent of the username, but for the server side. The Ticket-Granting Service knows about all Service Principals and their passwords, and encrypts the Service Ticket with that password. In order to acquire a Service Ticket for a certain service, obviously you must know its SPN.

Comment: So using the terminology you have used. The SPN is a username to connect to the Ticket-Granting Service (Active directory in this case). I take it the keytab file is some sort of password? Is this actually required though...is there something stopping me from passing through the username and password the client typed in on the webpage?

Comment: The key advantage of Kerberos is that it is a single sign-on system, which eliminates the need to contact the authentication authority for each request. The client does not know the password of the server, if that's what you are implying. `keytab` is on the server so the server knows its own password, which it needs to decrypt service tickets.

Comment: `Kerberos ... eliminates the need to contact the authentication authority for each request`. Surely this is the same for every auth system once you have an authenticated session?

`The client does not know the password of the server`. The mistake I made is that I forgot the client details are hashed before they are sent to my app server, so I can't then use them to "login" to the AD server.

`keytab is on the server so the server knows its own password`. So why not just use a password, why a file?

Comment: 1) Not necessarily, many systems use Basic Auth with SSL; but with Kerberos the server must *never* contact the authentication authority. Only the client does that. It's a "trusted 3rd party" system. 2) The server has its own password in a file; where else do you imagine it residing? Hardcoded into server code?

Comment: I've just realised my understanding of Kerberos was completely wrong, however what you have stated here: `but with Kerberos the server must never contact the authentication authority`, I'm not sure if the never was highlighted because its not always true, but why does my server configuration need to know about the server at all (because I have some server details in the config at the moment). If this is implementation specific (ie not kerberos specific) just say and Ill open another question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "why does my server configuration need to know about the server".

Comment: Not sure who has given you a downvote without an explanation. I meant that my application server requires SPNEGO specific configuration that contains details of my AD server. If all the information is already encrypted and send in the client handshake with my app server, and the app server doesn't need anything further to decrypt (ie doesn't need to talk to AD), why does it need to know the AD server details?

Comment: Don't worry about the downvote, I know what that's about :) You mean your serverside `kerb5.conf` has this information? I don't think those entries are actually needed; people tend to include them out of superstition and insufficient understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the information, the more questions I ask, the more off-topic from my original question we get so I will create a specific question if I require any further information - Thanks again.